# Symfony 3.4 $_SESSION in controller

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I have an app that starts in a `.php` file.
In this file I do some work, but at the end I do two things, I generate a value and save in `$_SESSION` and redirect to other route:

This `php` file is out of Symfony folder:

```
<?php
session_start();

...Do some work

$_SESSION['token'] = 'some value';
header ("Location: new direction");
?>
```

The redirection,redirects to symfony folder,and starts the symfony part going to my `src/AppBundle/Controller/MainController`.

And in the first action that is processed in this controller I need to access the value of `$_SESSION['token']` to do some work with this value in the controller action. This is the controller:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class MainController extends Controller
{
    public function homepageAction(Request $request)
    {
        dump($_SESSION);
        die;

        ...Some work
    }
}
?>
```

The `dump($_SESSION)` shows this:

[image]

But I can´t find my `$_SESSION['token']`

Do I need to use some Symfony component to access the PHP $_SESSION values inside a controller?

Or How can I access `$_SESSION['token']` in the controller?

Comment: Use the session class in HTTP foundation instead of accessing it directly. [Here's the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html)

Comment: But my first php file, is out of symfony folder, so how can I use `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;` and set the value with my `$_SESSION['token']`?. Or directly in `$session = new Session();` will be `token` value?

Comment: Use session object from container
```$this->get('session')->get('token');```

Comment: $session = $request->getSession();  will also get you the current session.

Comment: I have tried too, but nothing works, I think Symfony at some point is `overwriting` the session created in my first PHP file

Comment: I think it is more likely that you have two different url's resulting in two different session id's.  Maybe you can pass the token as part of the redirection.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to add that custom code into your Symfony application to avoid such hassles?

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to create route that accept token param, to stuff like saving token param in session, and redirect user.

If you need to duplicate this behavior for all your routes, use a listener on request event.

Edit : More informations about my answer

Step 1 : Set your token value

Step 2 : Redirect to Symfony route that accept token param

Step 3 : Apply your own logic based on token value

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;


/**
 * @Route("/{token}", defaults={"token"=null})
 */
class MainController extends Controller
{

    public function homepageAction(Request $request, SessionInterface $session, ?string $token)
    {
        if ($token) {
            $session->set('token', $token);
        }

        ...Some work
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide further information about that? Why is that the "best way" and what exactly should be done?

Answer (score 0):

I tryed all the things all of you suggest,and nothing convice me, so reading a post in a forum I fount this line:

`php_value session.auto_start 0`

I put that in my `.htaccess` file and Symfony doesn´t overwrite the `$_SESSION` variable anymore and I can access to it everywhere in the controllers.